# Debian 10: proper configuration for unattended-upgrades to update packages from unstable-repository

Tags: debian, unattended-upgrades

I have a Debian server (buster) with some packages from an unstable repository. Pin-Priority for unstable repository is 150. Now I want them to be updated by unattended-upgrades. Do I need this in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
"origin=Debian,codename=sid,label=Debian";
"origin=Debian,codename=sid,label=Debian-Security";
```

or is this enough?

```
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
```

or do I need a completely different configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add only the following line:

```
"origin=Debian,archive=unstable,label=Debian";
```

Then run:

```
unattended-upgrade -d --dry-run
```

In your case, the `${distro_codename}` = `buster`.

> [Q: How is security handled for unstable?](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#unstable)

> A: Security for unstable is primarily handled by package maintainers, not by the Debian Security Team. Although the security team may upload high-urgency security-only fixes when maintainers are noticed to be inactive, support for stable will always have priority. If you want to have a secure (and stable) server you are strongly encouraged to stay with stable.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. i needed the unstable-repo for wireguard. but now i just saw that it is now available in backports. so i think, can i disable the unstable again and be happy with the following? ```
"origin=Debian Backports,codename=${distro_codename}-backports,l=Debian Backports";
```